# SortedArray program not compiling

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I am currently having trouble compiling my c++ SortedArray program.I genuinely do not know where my program is wrong and would like to figure out the issue. It would be great if someone could help me out.I am wondering if maybe I am calling my functions improperly due to the pointer but have tried using arrow and dot operators. here is my source code

compiler error

```
In file included from SortedArray.cpp:1:0:
SortedArray.h:17:12: error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type
     friend ostream & operator (ostream & out, const SortedArray & sA);
            ^~~~~~~
SortedArray.cpp: In member function ‘void SortedArray::insertVal(int)’:
SortedArray.cpp:57:12: error: request for member ‘isFull’ in ‘((SortedArray*)this)->SortedArray::arr’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’
     if(arr.isFull())
            ^~~~~~
SortedArray.cpp:58:11: error: request for member ‘expand’ in ‘((SortedArray*)this)->SortedArray::arr’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’
       arr.expand();
           ^~~~~~
SortedArray.cpp: In member function ‘bool SortedArray::deleteVal(int)’:
SortedArray.cpp:86:17: error: request for member ‘find’ in ‘((SortedArray*)this)->SortedArray::arr’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’
   int index=arr.find(val);
                 ^~~~
SortedArray.cpp: At global scope:
SortedArray.cpp:97:2: error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type
  ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const SortedArray & sA){
  ^~~~~~~
```

//SortedArray.h

```
#ifndef SORTEDARRAY_H_
#define SORTEDARRAY_H_

class SortedArray
{
  public:
    SortedArray(int cap=10);
    ~SortedArray();
    int getCapacity();
    int getSize();
    bool isFull();
    bool isEmpty();
    void expand();
    void insertVal(int val);
    int find(int val);
    bool deleteVal(int val);
    friend ostream & operator (ostream & out, const SortedArray & sA);

  private:
    int capacity;
    int size;
    int *arr;
};
#endif
```

//SortedArray.cpp

```
#include "SortedArray.h"

SortedArray::SortedArray(int cap)
{
  capacity=cap;
  size=0;
  arr= new int[capacity];
}

SortedArray::~SortedArray()
{
  delete arr;
  size=0;
}
int SortedArray::getCapacity()
{
  return capacity;
}

int SortedArray::getSize()
{
  return size;
}

bool SortedArray::isFull()
{
  if(size==capacity);
    return true;

  return false;
}

bool SortedArray::isEmpty()
{

    if(size==0)
      return true;

    return false;
}

void SortedArray::expand()
{
    capacity=capacity*2;
    int *newArr=new int[capacity];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      newArr[i]=arr[i];
    }
    delete arr;
    arr=newArr;
}

void SortedArray::insertVal(int val)
{
    if(arr->isFull())
      arr->expand();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i]<=val)
      {
        for(int j =size;j>=i;j--)
        {
          arr[j+1]=arr[j];
        }
      }
      arr[i]=val;
      size++;
    }
}

int SortedArray::find(int val)
{
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    if(arr[i]=val)
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

bool SortedArray::deleteVal(int val){
  int index=arr->find(val);
  if(index==-1)
    return false;
  size--;
  for (int i=index;i<size;i++)
  {
    arr[i]= arr[i+1];
  }
  return true;
}

 ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const SortedArray & sA){
  for(int i = 0; i < sA.getSize(); i++) {
        out << sA.arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: `error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type ...` generally indicates a missing header file. I don't see any included.

Comment: Also, `ostream` is in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Also `arr` is an `int*`. It has no methods whatsoever. You probably meant `this->isFull()` instead of `arr->isFull()` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a large number of small problems. To begin in order to overload `<<` you must `#include <iostream>`

In `SortedArray.h`, you are missing the `<<` in:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const SortedArray& sA);
```

In `SortedArray.c`, you have a non-functioning `if` at:

```
if(size==capacity);        // remove the ';'
```

`isFull()` `expand()` and `find()` are not class member functions of non-class type `arr`. You simply need:

```
if (isFull())
    expand();
```

and

```
int index=find(val);
```

Your test for `if (arr[i]=val)` is a comparison, not an assignment, you need:

```
if(arr[i] == val)
```

Finally, in order to pass `const SortedArray& sA` in your overload of `<<`, then `sA.getSize()` must be constant, e.g. in both your header and source, you need:

```
int getSize() const;
```

and

```
int SortedArray::getSize() const
{
    return size;
}
```

If I remembered them all, then you should now be able to compile without warning. If you still have problems, just add a comment and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: thank you so much this fixed the issue. you are very appreciated!!